# What is VB6's equivalent to .NET Short?

Tags: .net, vb6, short

What is VB6's equivalent to .NET Short? I need a 2 byte number variable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent VB6 data type is [Integer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Data_Types).

Answer (score 3):

Its [**Integer**](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson2.html) in VB6

See that it matches the range with .net datatype [**short**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is a 2 byte number variable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx